# Using Pandas filtering non-numeric data from two columns of a Dataframe

Tags: excel, numpy, pandas

I'm loading a Pandas dataframe which has many data types (loaded from Excel).  Two particular columns should be floats, but occasionally a researcher entered in a random comment like "not measured."  I need to drop any rows where any values in one of two columns is not a number and preserve non-numeric data in other columns.  A simple use case looks like this (the real table has several thousand rows...)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]), B = pd.Series([96,33,45,'',8]), C = pd.Series([12,'Not measured',15,66,42]), D = pd.Series(['apples', 'oranges', 'peaches', 'plums', 'pears'])))
```

Which results in this data table:

```
    A   B   C               D
0   1   96  12              apples
1   2   33  Not measured    oranges
2   3   45  15              peaches
3   4       66              plums
4   5   8   42              pears
```

I'm not clear how to get to this table:

```
    A   B   C               D
0   1   96  12              apples
2   3   45  15              peaches
4   5   8   42              pears
```

I tried dropna, but the types are "object" since there are non-numeric entries.
I can't convert the values to floats without either converting the whole table, or doing one series at a time which loses the relationship to the other data in the row.  Perhaps there is something simple I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create subset with columns `B`,`C` and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), check if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) values are [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html). Then use [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df[['B','C']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull().all(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print df[df[['B','C']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull().all(axis=1)]
   A   B   C        D
0  1  96  12   apples
2  3  45  15  peaches
4  5   8  42    pears
```

Next solution use [`str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and xor (`^`):

```
print df['B'].str.isdigit().isnull() ^ df['C'].str.isdigit().notnull()
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print df[df['B'].str.isdigit().isnull() ^ df['C'].str.isdigit().notnull()]
   A   B   C        D
0  1  96  12   apples
2  3  45  15  peaches
4  5   8  42    pears
```

But solution with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) is fastest:

```
print df[pd.to_numeric(df['B'], errors='coerce').notnull() 
       ^ pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').isnull()]

   A   B   C        D
0  1  96  12   apples
2  3  45  15  peaches
4  5   8  42    pears
```

**Timings**:

```
#len(df) = 5k
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [611]: %timeit df[pd.to_numeric(df['B'], errors='coerce').notnull() ^ pd.to_numeric(df['C'], errors='coerce').isnull()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 ms per loop

In [612]: %timeit df[df['B'].str.isdigit().isnull() ^ df['C'].str.isdigit().notnull()]
100 loops, best of 3: 16.1 ms per loop

In [613]: %timeit df[df[['B','C']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notnull().all(axis=1)]
The slowest run took 4.28 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.49 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks!  I like the first solution with apply, notnull, for maintainability.  It seems to work!  I'll give it a day and see if there are any problems that pop up, or if someone responds with an even simpler solution.